# Which definition of "franchise" fits in this context?

Tags: meaning

Which definition of "franchise" fits best in this context?

> Despite the seemingly strong empirical support in previous studies for
>   theories of majoritarian democracy, our analyses suggest that
>   majorities of the American public actually have little influence over
>   the policies our government adopts. Americans do enjoy many features
>   central to democratic governance, such as regular elections, freedom
>   of speech and association, and a widespread (if still contested)
>   **franchise**. But we believe that if policymaking is dominated by powerful business organizations and a small number of affluent
>   Americans, then America’s claims to being a democratic society are
>   seriously threatened.

1. The right to vote?
2. The rights of citizenship?
3. The right to carry out specified commercial activities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right to vote.

*Franchise* has that sense as a specific from of the second definition you list, but that the franchise is widespread (rather than restricted to a specific group) is both something that fits alongside the other features listed, something that has not always been enjoyed in the country in question (which would hence make it more immediately come to mind) and which is indeed still contested with laws which those opposed claim are an attempt to restrict the franchise.

Answer (score 0):

My answer: 1. The right to vote

Franchise
word origin & history late 13c., from O.Fr. franchise "freedom," from variant stem of franc "free" (see frank). Sense narrowed 18c. to "particular legal privilege," then "right to vote" (1790).

The second meaning, the rights of citizenship, rarely enters public discourse today. When it does it is in negation i.e., as *dis*enfranchise (v.) "to deprive of civil... privileges," 1640s, from *dis- + enfranchise*. Earlier form was disfranchise (mid-15c.). Related: Disenfranchised; disenfranchisement.

The third meaning of franchise, the "authorization by a company to sell its products or services" is from 1959, and probably has no bearing upon the subject matter in question.

Etymology from etymonline.com